# Alternative to INDEX in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following formula:

```
=iferror(index(A25:A50,A1), true)
```

> A1 = any number between 0 and 26

[Given that the excel formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) `index` returns the entire array if the `row_num` parameter passed is `0`, is there a way to do something similar (pass an `array` and a `row_num` and get the value from that row) that returns an `error` if the `row_num` is `0`?

I tried using `indirect("A"&A1+25)` which does return an error if `A1 = 0` however I have to add `25` so then I never have `0`, which doesn't work.

I also tried another way:

```
=iferror(hlookup(index(A25:A50,1),A25:A50,A1,false),true)
```

However the downside is the amount of times `A25:A50` is repeated. This is only a segment in my final formula where `A25:A50` (and `A1`) will be replaced by a *very long* formula so the least I can repeat it the better.

Basically I am looking for an alternative way than `index` (or the way I am using `index`) to find the value of a row in an array based on its `row_num`, which returns an error if the `row_num` passed is `0`.

Comment: `=iferror(index(A25:A50, A1+1), true)` provides a value from A25:A50 where A1 = any number between 0 and 25 (there are 26 possible values in A25:A50)

Comment: @Jeeped good point. I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDEX(A25:A50,IF(A1>0,A1,NA()))
```

Comment: Yes, this does work. Do you know of a way to not have to repeat A1 twice? In my final formula, `A1` (and `A25:A50`) will be it's own very long formula that I'd rather not have to put in twice (for "continuity" sake if I end up having to update some part of the formula in the future).

Comment: Cool...can you mark my answer as accepted. Yes, you must repeat the A1 twice. Just keep the long logic for A1 in a separate cell, like in the actual example you posted.